# Trouble with Python returning a value

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to writing Python programs and I'm struggling to write this particular exercise from https://www.codecademy.com/resources/blog/python-code-challenges-for-beginners/

In exercise 2, I'm to sort a list. This is what I have so far, but it keeps failing saying the order is not defined. I'm not sure where to define the functions so the if and elif statements trigger, any help is appreciated:

---

```
"""create a function with two parameters"""
def digits(num_list, order):
    if order == 'asc':
        print(digits(num_list.sort()))
    elif order == 'desc':
        print(digits(num_list.sort(reverse=True)))
    else:
        print(digits(num_list))


digit_list = [12, 15, 2, 7, 8, 25, 5, 45, 2]

digits(digit_list, 'asc')
```

Comment: It looks like you are causing some sort of infinite loop. Why are you calling the function digits() inside of the print function which is inside of the function itself?

Comment: Also, the code you provided fails with the error `TypeError: digits() missing 1 required positional argument: 'order'`, not the one you say you get.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953).

Comment: Digits is not defined when you call digits inside of the function. Therefore, nothing is being passed through. Remove digits() from the print function entirely and just do the sorting.

Comment: ```def digits(num_list, order):
    if order == 'asc':
        print(num_list.sort())
    elif order == 'desc':
        print(num_list.sort(reverse=True))
    else:
        print(num_list)
```

Comment: @NicholasGati _"Digits is not defined ... nothing is being passed through"_ The function is never called, since it did not get enough arguments.

Comment: Also @NicholasGati if you want to answer the question, please post an answer. Comments are not meant for answers.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi a function can indeed be called with insufficient arguments

Comment: @NicholasGati no it can't. You can call a function that has _default_ arguments, and in that situation the argument that is not specified gets the default valule, but that is not the case here. All arguments must be defined to call a function

Comment: He called the function in the final line of the code which includes the `order`. However, inside of the `digits()` function, he calls the function itself again creating recursion but with insufficient arguments. Thus, `order` is no longer defined. It should error out at that point.

Comment: @Mark your question's title must summarize your actual question. _"Trouble with codecademy exercise 2 issue"_ fails to do that because it doesn't tell us what your question is. Remember that people haven't memorized the codeacademy exercises

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Right. For some reason when writing the initial comment, I was under the impression there was a default value. In some other languages, like JS, insufficient arguments are allowed and the missing argument is `undefined`.

Comment: Hello, Mark. May you please accept my answer if it has helped you? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your function is recursive, when you don't want it to be.
On line 4, see how `print(digits(num_list.sort()))` is calling the digits function again- with no order parameter defined?

When a parameter is optional, it is best to give it as a keyword argument with a default value. Like `order=None`.

Also when you call `list.sort`, it sorts the list **in-place** returning no output. What you want here is the built-in `sorted` function, or call the `list.sort` before printing.

`doc-strings` should be put inside a function to come up when the `help` function is called upon the function.

This seems to be the code you were going after.

```py
def digits(num_list, order=None):
    """create a function with two parameters"""
    if order == 'asc':
        print(sorted(num_list))
    elif order == 'desc':
        print(sorted(num_list, reverse=True))
    else:
        print(num_list)


digit_list = [12, 15, 2, 7, 8, 25, 5, 45, 2]

digits(digit_list, 'asc')
```

Please let me know how it went! Welcome to Python!

Edit: 2nd method with `list.sort`

```py
def digits(num_list, order=None):
    """create a function with two parameters"""
    if order:
        num_list.sort(reverse=(order == 'desc'))
    print(num_list)


digit_list = [12, 15, 2, 7, 8, 25, 5, 45, 2]

digits(digit_list, 'asc')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I knew I was missing something simple! The function works fine now.

Comment: @MarkFraher That's great to hear, my friend! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your first error (and the one Python is complaining about) is on this line:

```
print(digits(num_list.sort()))
```

While you are within the `digits` function, you are calling `digits` recursively. In your original post, you had set up `digits` to take two mandatory arguments, `num_list` and `order`. The line above doesn't have the second mandatory argument (`order`). That's why you're getting the error.

(I noticed that you have changed your code to make `order` optional; this creates a new problem, namely infinite recursion.)

When you write a Python function, you often want it to return something (rather than print something).

Here is a function that returns the list (either sorted, reverse sorted, or without change).

```
"""create a function with two parameters"""
def digits(num_list, order):
    if order == 'asc':
        num_list.sort()
    elif order == 'desc':
        num_list.sort(reverse=True)
    return num_list
```

You can invoke the function with:

```
digit_list = [12, 15, 2, 7, 8, 25, 5, 45, 2]

digits(digit_list, 'asc')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this but I do notice that you are updating the argument itself instead of just returning the altered result. Why not have the return inside of the `if` and `elif`?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this doesn't answer the question at all. Sure, it fixes the issue, but you didn't explain why the issue was fixed. OP isn't asking about printing vs. returning, OP is asking about an "order is not defined" error

Comment: Fair point, @NicholasGati. But note that a return a ```return num_list.sort()``` returns a None. I was trying to keep much of the OP's code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi added an explanation of the original problem.